# mysql , max ,groub by

Tags: mysql, sql, database, max

I'am using mysql database and I'am trying to develop a messages system for private application

i try to get from this table

[click to see the photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2I0cn.jpg)

to get the information group by ad_id and table_name 
 with the row have max messages_id

how can i do that whit this table 
thanks

Comment: Please don't use images--it makes it harder for us to use the information to help you. Also, Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to improve your question.

Comment: thank for reply and i update the photo , i hope to help me thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

suggest that if your above SQL statement can query the result.
maybe you can just skip the "order by" and simply just

```
select * from (/* your SQL statement without "order by"*/) a order by a.message_id desc
```

sorry that as it is difficult to see your screen capture and help you to resolve the SQL script.

Comment: thanks for reply , sorry about the photo i update the photo now

Comment: its work thanks brother

Comment: i just try to select all row with blue backgorund , i solve the first part that with the max messages_id , have the second part that with select all row with blue background as on the photo thanks a lot